# Detecting Amharic Language using regular expression in C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm working on a C# project that only accept Amharic language from the user and I want to use regular expression to evaluate the input.

This is the function that I found that works for Latin words. I want this same function to work for Amharic words by only changing the regular expression.

```
private static bool IsAmharicText(string text)
{
    string pattern = @"\p{IsLatin}";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

    return matches.Count > 0;
}
```

I have already researched and found that Amharic characters fall within the Ethiopic script range (Unicode range: 1200-137F). I want to use regular expressions to match these characters.

I want to create a regular expression pattern to evaluate if a given text contains Amharic characters.

I appreciate if you can give me a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you knew the character range, things get incredibly easy: [`[\u1200-\u137F]`](https://regex101.com/r/ZHw58O/1)

Alternatively, you can use the Unicode property notation: [`\p{IsEthiopic}`](https://regex101.com/r/ZHw58O/2)

More information on Unicode categories/scripts/blocks can be found at the excellent [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).